# RTC timer set point problem

Tags: programming

This is the timer part of my code:

```
int onHourONE = 11;
int onMinuteONE = 00;
int offHourONE = 23;
int offMinuteONE = 00;
byte PWMstatus = 0;

void setup{}

void loop{
    if ((now.hour() >= onHourONE) && (now.minute() >= onMinuteONE)) {
      PWMstatus = 1;
    }
    if ((now.hour() >= offHourONE) && (now.minute() >= offMinuteONE)) {
      PWMstatus = 2;
    }
    if (PWMstatus == 1) {
      // do this
    }
    if (PWMstatus == 2) {
      // do that
}
```

It's working just fine but the problem is if i set the `offhourONE` less than `onhourONE` it will keep the LED OFF.

for example the time is now 14:00

`onhourONE` and `offminuteONE` is also set on 14:00

`offhourONE` and `offminuteONE` is set on 13:00

So in this case it should keep the LED ON until tomorrow 13:00 **but** it stays OFF obviously because of this statement:

```
if ((now.hour() >= offHourONE) && (now.minute() >= offMinuteONE)) {}
```

I can change that to this:

```
if ((now.hour() == offHourONE) && (now.minute() == offMinuteONE)) {}
```

But then it will only turn OFF the LED at that specific time, in this case if i restart the Arduino like 1 minute after it turned OFF it will turn on again while it should stay off until it reaches the set point of turn ON.

*I know it sounds simple but seems confusing to me, any guidance appreciated...*

Comment: i was writing as i was thinking ... 37:00 = 13:00 + 24:00 ... add 24 hours to turn off time

Comment: you can figure this out by drawing a diagram ... circle ... `0` at top `12` at bottom ... that is 24 hours ....  add 24 hours to stop time .... then use something like this pseudo code  `if (T>=14 && T+24 <=37) then ON else OFF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add more logic to your program.

As mentioned in another answer you really want to be working with just the highest resolution time interval that matters to you - that is minutes in your case.  Convert your hour and minutes of the day into the number of minutes since midnight:

```
onTime = onHourONE * 60 + onMinuteONE;
offTime = offHourONE * 60 + offHourONE;
```

And convert the current time to minutes since midnight:

```
timeNow = now.hour() * 60 + now.minute();
```

Now comes the tricky bit, but since you are now just working with single numbers it's far easier.  You now need to work out *what* you are doing.

You have a couple of scenarios:

1. onTime < offTime - eg: 12:00 to 17:00
2. onTime > offTime - eg: 21:00 to 03:00

You need to make your decision in a different way depending on which scenario you are in - and comparing a single number with a single number is so much easier than messing with hours and minutes.

So, you can do something like:

```
if (onTime < offTime) {
    if ((timeNow >= onTime) && (timeNow < offTime)) {
      // On!
    } else {
      // Off!
    }
} else {
    if ((timeNow >= onTime) || (timeNow < offTime)) {
      // On!
    } else {
      // Off!
    }
}
```

In English:

- If the start time is before the end time:

  - If the time is both greater than the start time and less than the end time, then it's on.
  - Otherwise it's off.
- Otherwise, of the start time is after the end time:

  - If the time is greater than the start time, *or* it's less than the end time, then it's on.
  - Otherwise it's off.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, that `now` after first `if` is `timeNow`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I edited my answer. Well spotted.

Comment: I just tested it and it's working. thanks again. quick question; can i combine that `if` after `else` together like this `else if(){}`?

Comment: Possibly, but it's more logical laid out the way I have it. You can instantly see the meaning, and it won't make it any more or less efficient to run.

Answer (score 1):

If it overly complicated to use a combination of seconds, minutes and hours for comparisons. For this you can use the time in seconds, as you get it with `now.secondstime()` or `now.unixtime()`. If you don't want to look at the seconds (so only values multiple to 60), you can do an integer division to get the minutes `now.secondstime()/60`.

To calculate the needed limit values from the combination of hour and minutes, just multiply according to the unit. For seconds `(hour*60+minutes)*60`. For minutes `hour*60+minutes`.

Comment: unixtime for a time in current day? and how does using minutes of day solve the question?